# Settingup System properties in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to setup the system properties on the Tomcat, and access this property from code using:
`System.getProperty(key)`

Comment: So do it. Whats the problem ?

Comment: how to setup this key while startup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the property as a directive for the JVM in your tomcat startup script
JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Dmy.custom.key=CustomKey

Comment: It would be better to create CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh or .bat script and set the variables into the script rather than editing the startup script (catalina.sh or .bat) directly.

Comment: ...and I recommend to set CATALINA_OPTS: This will be used only for startup while JAVA_OPTS is used for all JVM starts, including the brief start that is used for shutdown

Comment: `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsystemprop=value`